# Can't boot into ubuntu after missing to enroll MOK when installing NVIDIA driver

Tags: boot, drivers, dual-boot, nvidia

first of all, my knowledge of Linux is so humble and I'm still learning so please bear with me. The problem that I'm facing happened after I followed a tutorial to download Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu, where I used 'sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525 nvidia-dkms-525' command which ended up showing me a message regarding UEFI Secure Boot and prompted me to enter a password to use it later after I reboot to enroll MOK. After I restarted my laptop, I selected continue to reboot instead of enroll MOK though. Now, my ubuntu is not booting and its showing the alert UUID=xxx doesnt exist and BusyBox shell Initramfs. Is there a way to maybe get the MOK management screen again to enter the password or my system and files are gone already? By the way, Im running ubuntu along with windows on my laptop (dual boot).

Comment: Try turning off secure boot, then the unsigned nvidia modules should not prevent booting.